# Dynamically adding UIImageView's from an array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want dynamically to add an array of UIImageViews to a view. When I iterate through a for loop it seems that only the last UIImageView is added, instead of all from the array:

```
// same image to be used 
let imageName = "img.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

// array of UIImageViews
var images : [UIImageView?] = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: UIImageView(image: image))

// iterate and add to view
for i in 0...9 {

    // setup UIImageView
    // this is how I know only the last UIImageView is added to the parent view
    // the y cordinate is about 10 points down (this is expected of i+i array size with of 10)

    images[i]?.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: CGFloat(i+i), width: image!.size.width, height: image!.size.height)   

    // add to parent view
    parentView.addSubview(images[i]!)

}
```

Is there a simple fix to this? I feel as if I am missing something blatant.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint on the parentView and looked at its subviews array?

Comment: @Helium3 I could find that array in the debug console, however I logged out all of the subviews in the parent and only 1 UIImageView was logged

Comment: also when I log out the subviews while inside of the original for loop, each different UIImageView does get logged, they just seem to replace one another

Comment: and now that I observe that, they all use the same CALAYER id when being logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `Array(count: 10, repeatedValue: UIImageView(image: image))`, `repeatedValue` means the all imageviews you're gonna add to this array is referenced to a same object. In this way, you only have one imageview, how can it be added as many copys.  Check my answer.[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWidth = 40
        let myHeight = 40

        // same image to be used
        let imageName = "img.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        // iterate and add to view
        for i in 0...9 {
            var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: myHeight * i, width: myWidth, height: myHeight)

            // add to parent view
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is defintley the answer that I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

repeatedValue: UIImageView(image: image)) is just passing the same reference to the same object into the array. So you have an array of 10 references to the same image.

Trying this for a test will show that the function will work when passed a correct imageview array

```
var images : [UIImageView] = [UIImageView(image: image), UIImageView(image: image), UIImageView(image: image), UIImageView(image: image), UIImageView(image: image)]
```

You should then have 5 UIImageViews added as subviews.

It doesnt really make sense to use the same image in the array, unless its just for your test. You might be better of creating a Set of images so that there will only be unique images. The unique images can then be used to create UIImageViews.